# C server socket closed but client socket still able send two more packages

Tags: c, sockets

I am learning socket on c. I have a client and a server, when the server closed the socket, the client still able to receive and sent to server two more packages before the send get a SIGPIPE signal. I don't know why. Can anyone help pls~

since the documentation said that if the `send` and `recv` have error then they will return -1. But this never happen in my case here.

Client side

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <signal.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <sys/socket.h>
#include    <netinet/in.h>
#include    <arpa/inet.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE  255
#define MAXLENG     96
#define true        1
#define false       0

void exitp();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    signal(SIGPIPE, exitp);
    // Check if the argument is match the requirement
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Useage Error, should be follow by ip, and port\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create the socket for the client, if the fd for the socket == -1, it means
    // it created fail
    int skfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (skfd  < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Create socket failed\n" );
        exit(1);
    }


    int PORT = atoi(argv[2]);

    // Set up server argument
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    memset(&server_addr, '0', sizeof(server_addr)); // addr for bin
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // ip not vaild
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &server_addr.sin_addr) < 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "IP address not correct\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    // create the connection
    if (connect(skfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1){ // Connect to server
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection Fail\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    char sentbuff[255], recvbuffer[255], input[255], request[100], concelbuffer[255];


    // Send the request to the server
    int nn;
    int size = send(skfd, request, sizeof(request),0);
    while(1){
        if (recv(skfd, &recvbuffer,sizeof(recvbuffer),0) == -1){
            printf("Server Closed\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("%s",recvbuffer);
        fgets(sentbuff, 255, stdin);
        nn=send(skfd, &sentbuff, sizeof(sentbuff), 0);
        if (nn == -1){
        printf("Server Closed\n");
        break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


void exitp(){
    printf("%s\n","Server Closed" );
    exit(0);
}
```

server side I used `shutdown` and `close` for the `acceptfd`

Comment: I don't know how to explain your observations other than to say that the client is slamming the server and the server may take some time to shut down.  What I would do is add a shutdown command to the message protocol so that it is not an unexpected event and can be handled more gracefully than reacting to an error condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send()` just puts the data in the kernel socket buffer, it doesn't wait for the data to be transmitted or the server to acknowledge receipt of it.

You don't get `SIGPIPE` until the data is transmitted and the server rejects it by sending a `RST` segment.

It works this way because each direction of a TCP connection is treated independently. When the server closes the socket, it sends a `FIN` segment. This just tells the client that the server is done sending data, it doesn't mean that the server cannot receive data. There's nothing in the TCP protocol that allows the server to inform the client of this. So the only way to find out that it's not accepting any more data is when the client gets that `RST` response.

Informing the client that they shouldn't send anything more is usually done in the application protocol, since it's not available in TCP.